# Render Node by Id in Umbraco 4.11

Tags: asp.net, xml, razor, webforms, umbraco

**TL;DR** How do you render a content item by Node Id.

I'm using Widget Grid admin extension for Umbraco to configure a content manageable widget area and I'm stuck trying to render the configured widgets.

I have a list of node id's that I want to render on the page but I can for the life of me work out how to do this.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Xml contained within the Models property

```
<WidgetGrid> 
    <col1> <nodeId>4839</nodeId> <nodeId>4844</nodeId> <nodeId>4845</nodeId> </col1>
</WidgetGrid>
```

Once I get down to col1 it seems to cease being of type DynamicXml and just spits it out as a string... No idea.

Comment: Webforms (unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're doing this from within a macro, and I'm going to presume you have a multi-node picker set to store the Id values as CSV:

```
@{
    string[] widgetIds = ((string)Model.Widgets).Split(',');

    foreach (var id in widgetIds)
    {
        var widget = Model.NodeById(id);

        @RenderPage("~/macroscripts/widgets/" + widget.NodeTypeAlias
                         + ".cshtml", widget);
    }
}
```

This will let you select different types of widget in your multi-node picker, and have a different view for each widget.

This also uses the dynamic approach but you could easily adapt this by swapping the first line for:

```
string[] podIds = CurrentModel.GetProperty<string>("widgets").Split(',');
```

Given that the property is stored as XML, you can use the notation as described in this post (http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/2/28/umbraco-razor-feature-walkthrough-%E2%80%93-part-3):

```
foreach (var id in Model.widgets.col1[0].nodeId)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Its storing the Id's as xml, to a point. I've added the XML in the question.

Comment: Switch to CSV rather than xml if you are using the multi-node picker. Then you can split the nodeid's on `,` Remember to republish to see the changes in your node data.